# Batch - Choice Command with a variable choice

Tags: batch-file, variables, arraylist

I would like to know if it would be possible to do the choice /c command with a variable choice.

Example of what's in my head:

```
@echo off
set "list=Bob,Adam,Steve" 
set amount=3 

for /l %%i in (1; 1; %amount%) do call :sub %%i

goto chooseName
:sub
for /f "tokens=%1 delims=," %%a in ("%list%") do echo %%i. %%a
goto :eof

:chooseName
choice /c %amount% /m "What name do you want to choose"

if errorlevel 3 do ...
if errorlevel 2 do ...
if errorlevel 1 do ...
```

The creation of the list works fine and it gives me the option to select form the list but only says:

```
What name do you want to choose: [3]?
```

So I need to change this part of the code:

```
choice /c 123 /m "What name do you want to choose"
```

So that instead of having "123" it will take a variable (in this case the lenght of the list) so that if I add a name to the list it will allow you to enter 1, 2, 3 or 4 and if I take a name out it will go backt to giving you 3 choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is completely doable, you just need to create your list.

Now that said you do realise that choice only allows 0-9, A-Z a-z and ASCII Characters from 128 through 254, correct?

That is to say, you need to use the list of characters to create the choice selection and just select the number of choices you want.

**here is the List of characters usable with Choice:**

`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z Ç ü é â ä à å ç ê ë è ï î ì Ä Å É æ Æ ô ö ò û ù ÿ Ö Ü ¢ £ ¥ ₧ ƒ á í ó ú ñ Ñ ª º ¿ ⌐ ¬ ½ ¼ ¡ « » ░ ▒ ▓ │ ┤ ╡ ╢ ╖ ╕ ╣ ║ ╗ ╝ ╜ ╛ ┐ └ ┴ ┬ ├ ─ ┼ ╞ ╟ ╚ ╔ ╩ ╦ ╠ ═ ╬ ╧ ╨ ╤ ╥ ╙ ╘ ╒ ╓ ╫ ╪ ┘ ┌ █ ▄ ▌ ▐ ▀ α ß Γ π Σ σ µ τ Φ Θ Ω δ ∞ φ ε ∩ ≡ ± ≥ ≤ ⌠ ⌡ ÷ ≈ ° ∙ · √ ⁿ ² ■`

Now to use those you can't have spaces of course but for the pickig fo the characters you'll need them.

### Here is a sample script that accomplished your goal:

```
@(SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  ECHO OFF
  set "_ChoiceList=Bob,Adam,Steve,Alex,Durand,Killian,Hello,There,Now,Is,Going,Past"
  REM Full Character List to populate Choices
  SET "_CharList=0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z Ç ü é â ä à å ç ê ë è ï î ì Ä Å É æ Æ ô ö ò û ù ÿ Ö Ü ¢ £ ¥ ₧ ƒ á í ó ú ñ Ñ ª º ¿ ⌐ ¬ ½ ¼ ¡ « » ░ ▒ ▓ │ ┤ ╡ ╢ ╖ ╕ ╣ ║ ╗ ╝ ╜ ╛ ┐ └ ┴ ┬ ├ ─ ┼ ╞ ╟ ╚ ╔ ╩ ╦ ╠ ═ ╬ ╧ ╨ ╤ ╥ ╙ ╘ ╒ ╓ ╫ ╪ ┘ ┌ █ ▄ ▌ ▐ ▀ α ß Γ π Σ σ µ τ Φ Θ Ω δ ∞ φ ε ∩ ≡ ± ≥ ≤ ⌠ ⌡ ÷ ≈ ° ∙ · √ ⁿ ² ■"
)

CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
  EXIT /B 0
)

:Main


  REM Now we can Do Our Choices btu lets do it in a Sub Function.
  CALL :MakeChoice _ChoiceResult
  ECHO.
  ECHO The Index Chosen Was: %_Chosen%
  ECHO The Result Matched is:  %_ChoiceResult%

GOTO :EOF

:MakeChoice
  cls
  color 1A
  SET %~1="
  SET "_Choices="
  SET "_Chosen="
  SET "_Amount="
  SET "_Choice#="
  echo.      Pick a Name:
  echo.========================

  REM Create Numbered Array of Choices and output Choices to the Screen
  FOR %%A IN (!_ChoiceList!) DO (
    SET /A "_Amount+=1"
    REM ECHO !_Amount!
    REM ECHO.SET "_Choice.!_Amount!.Value=%%A"
    SET "_Choice.!_Amount!.Value=%%A"  )
  ECHO.

  REM Create Choice List to Display only the choices needed.
  FOR %%A IN (%_CharList%) DO (
    SET /A "_Temp+=1"
    IF !_Temp! LEQ !_Amount! (
      SET "_Choices=!_Choices!%%A"
      CALL ECHO. %%A :    %%_Choice.!_Temp!.Value%%
    )
  )
  ECHO.

  CHOICE /CS /C !_Choices! /N /M "What name do you want to choose? "
  SET "_Chosen=%ERRORLEVEL%"

  REM Set Return Variable Value:
  SET "%~1=!_Choice.%_Chosen%.Value!"
GOTO :EOF
```

In the above Script we have created a Generic Choice Function, an we pass it a value we want to have used to return the value of the chosen choice into.

In the Choice Function we parse the list of choices (that could also have been sent as a pointer to the list of choices instead) and then we count them, echoing the number of the choice and the .. oops I realise I used the Numeric choices method only of having `SET /A` its a neat trick but won;t work for lettered choices, nor will it show the initial leading 0 choice.

Okay I'll amend that.

but in any case we create Variables for the choices and associate them with a numeric value (which is all that is returned by choice anyway) so we an then choose the correct index value.

We let the user make the choice and then use that to populate the return variable with the result value, we also still have the original choice value returned as well since we have saved that in `_Chosen` so if you want to work off of the actual value you can.

You can however also create a list of Actions to run that woudl also be populated using a similar method to creating the list of choices themselves and then simply match the action as it will be saved in a variable the same was we match the value.

Alright you should have the lish show up correctly now.

Alrighty I realised I needed to add in that to be a call and had some wrongly named variables blah blah blah.

Long Story Short I amended as Above and had time to test to be sure it was working as expected.

Here are example Results:

```
      Pick a Name:
========================

 0 :    Bob
 1 :    Adam
 2 :    Steve
 3 :    Alex
 4 :    Durand
 5 :    Killian
 6 :    Hello
 7 :    There
 8 :    Now
 9 :    Is
 A :    Going
 B :    Past

What name do you want to choose? 7

The Index Chosen Was: 8
The Result Matched is:  There
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a bit to Ben's answer (not really feasible in the comments) --

You could define a variable with all possible answers for choice in order; and then use your variable `amount` to return the substring as appropriate.

Another point -- instead of all the `if errorlevel` statements you could call a variable label instead.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set allchoices=123456789abcdefg
set amount=6

choice /c !allchoices:~0,%amount%! /m "What do you want to choose? "

goto :choice%errorlevel%
rem You'll get an error if there isn't a label that corresponds to :choice%errorlevel%

:choice1
echo You chose 1
pause
goto :eof

:choice10
echo You chose a
pause
goto :eof
```

Of course make sure you define all the labels and make sure your allchoices is large enough for any amount you might need.

Comment: That's a true, however, you need to list the values you are choosing somewhere matched to their choice number or it's not of much value. 
 But yes, if you truly only needed to choose and return that certain value then you could do that. NOTE: You would probably want to use the character of the index in each of your choice labels, just in case you ended up changing which characters were in what order so you wouldn;t also have ot change your bale indexea

Comment: Like I said, I was just adding to your answer a bit and generalizing some.  I too would use the concept of `!variable%count%!` to get and match things and later `!variable%errorlevel%!`.  But that's more than what the OP actually asked for -- which they may or may not choose to utilize.

Comment: Sorry ran out to time editing NOTE: You would probably want to use the character of the index in each of your choice labels, just in case you ended up changing which characters were in what order so you wouldn't also have to change your bale indexes (ie `:Choice_A` instead of `:Choice10`  then you can `CALL :Choice%_allchoices:~%errorlevel%,1%

Comment: If you look at OPs code he has a list of Values he wants to display and displays them in his loops in a way that suggests he tried to create the loist with [Choice]  [Value] , obviously in his code that wouldn;t display right.  SO that is why I interpreted it to be an intended portion of the question.   By the By, I love your Username.  It's Excellent!

Comment: And I appreciate you are adding to it, like I said it would be useful if you only need the list of choices to be given, then it's definitely the best method.  Just giving you some understanding why OPs Q really wanted the more complex answer.  I'd say however that mine is probably technically more generic, although I do have the habit of not liking to trust Errorlevel as it's own variable etc, I could tighten the code soe probably but I mostly wrote this on my phone and just ran a quick test of it on my computer when I had a moment.  So aytime it isn;t a typo mess is a win ;)

Comment: Also on your second point with the labels I agree that's how I would generally do the labels if I was using it for choices, except as amended above and that I would probably still return the result inside a variable to the main portion of the script and let that call the label, but mostly because I would expect use cases where youw oudl loop the menu if the user exit the choice incorrectly as I probably should amend my code to do.

Comment: In any case I do think you added some nice discussion and extra things to consider outside of the original question scope and within it, and so you've certainly got my Upvote for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Although this looks quite different, this uses basically the same technique as Ben.
It's straight forward (without subroutines) and uses only a subset of all possible characters. I put the capitals at the end because it's easier to type `a` than `A`. That reduces the number of choices, but IMHO it makes no sense to use characters that you can't easily use with your keyboard (and if you really should have more than 60 choices, you should think about a more userfriendly approach)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  

set "list=Bob,Adam,Steve,Alex,Bart,Charles,Dough,Emil,Fritz,Gustav" 
set "allchoices=123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
set count=0
for %%A in (%list%) do (
  call echo %%allchoices:~!count!,1%%: %%A
  set /a count+=1
  set "list[!count!]=%%A"
)
set "choices=!allchoices:~0,%count%!"
choice /cs /c %choices% /m "What name do you want to choose"
echo that would be !list[%errorlevel%]!
goto :sub%errorlevel%
:sub0
echo Control-C is mean...
goto :eof
:sub1
echo Hello Bob
goto :eof
REM etc...
```